# exception using Flutter share module

Tags: dart, flutter

I have created a flutter app using Android Studio and am adding some code to implement the social media share function using this package [https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/share].

I modified the code so the share function is called each time the floating  button is tapped/clicked.

I added `share: ^0.5.3` to pub spec.yaml and import the package. I added a line to the increment counter function as follows

`

```
void _incrementCounter() {
    Share.share('check out my website https://example.com');
    setState(() {
        _counter++;
});
```

`

Everything runs fine until I press the button and then I get the following exception:

VERBOSE-2:shell.cc(181)] Dart Error: Unhandled exception:
MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method share on channel plugins.flutter.io/share)

Any help appreciated :)

Comment: I tried on a phone running iOS 11.4.1 and get:
error: Multiple commands produce '/Volumes/Data/dev/apps/flutter_share_app/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.app/Frameworks/Flutter.framework':

and warning about swift3 inferences being deprecated in swift4

Comment: Try running `flutter clean` and then running the app again.

Comment: Did a clean and tried to launch and got the following error in the Xcode build:

code's output:
↳
    error: Multiple commands produce '/Volumes/Data/dev/apps/fshare/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/Frameworks/Flutter.framework':
    1) Target 'Runner' has copy command from '/Volumes/Data/dev/apps/fshare/ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework' to '/Volumes/Data/dev/apps/fshare/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/Frameworks/Flutter.framework'
    2) That command depends on command in Target 'Runner': script phase “[CP] Embed Pods Frameworks”

Comment: Ah okay. This is a known issue with XCode 10, check out this issue: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/20685

Answer (score 0):

It seems that these problems are caused by the new build system Apple introduced in Xcode 10. There is more info here [github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/20685#issuecomment-421511890](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/20685#issuecomment-421511890)

I have changed from the beta channel to the master channel and now have the example code provided by the Share package authors running in the simulator and on a device.